# Integral too big

Tags: decorations, integral

[image]

Integral become too big.
Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{cmap}     
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}    
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}   

\begin{proof}[Решение]   
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{e5}\\   

$E_{0}$ - Напряженность на поверхности Земли. $E_{h}$ - Напряженность на высоте $h$.    
\\ Рассмотрим $\rho = \rho(h)$.     
\\ Теорема Гаусса в дифференциальной форме:     
$$div\overrightarrow{E} = 4\pi\rho$$     
Направление вдоль оси Oy:     
$$E_{0}' = 4\pi\rho(0)$$    
$$E_{h}' = 4\pi\rho(h)$$    
Тогда проинтегрируем разность (ответ в СГСЭ):    
$$E_{h} - E_{0} = 4 \pi \int\nolimits_{0}^{h}p(\xi)d\xi$$     
$$\rho = \frac{E_{h} - E_{0}}{4\pi h} = \frac{75\cdot\frac{1}    {3}\cdot10^{-2}}{4\pi\cdot1,5\cdot10^{-3}} = 1,3\cdot10^{-5}$$     
\end{proof}
```

What should I do to decrease integral?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  You MWE is missing the `\begin{document}` after `\usepackage{geometry}`  and `\end{document}`.  If I add those, I do get a normal sized integral.

Comment: This is just some speciality of the (awful) [PDF.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF.js) viewer.  Try changing the viewer to »native« and try again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a viewer issue.